# Probability of winning in a lottery

Tags: probability

A player in the Powerball lottery picks five different integers between 1 and 59, inclusive, and a sixth integer between 1 and 39, which may duplicate one of the earlier
five integers.
What is the probability that a player wins $100 by matching exactly three of the first five and the sixth numbers or four of the first five numbers but not the sixth number?

My Answer:

Let us call the picking of 5 different integers between 1 and 59 (inclusive) as FIRST DRAW

and picking the sixth integer between 1 and 39 (inclusive) as SECOND DRAW.

Let $E_1$ be an Event having 3 out of 5 integers correctly matching the lottery pick in the first draw and also getting the correct match in the second draw.
$$p\left(E_1\right)=\frac{\left( \begin{array}{c}
54 \\ 
2 \end{array}
\right)}{\left(\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{59}{5}\right)}*\left(\frac{1}{39}\right)$$

Let $E_2$ be an Event having 4 out of 5 integers correctly matching the lottery pick in the first draw but getting a wrong match in the second draw.
$$p\left(E_2\right)=\frac{\left( \begin{array}{c}
54 \\ 
1 \end{array}
\right)}{\left( \begin{array}{c}
59 \\ 
5 \end{array}
\right)}*\left(\frac{38}{39}\right)$$

$$p\left(E\right)=p\left(E_1\right)+p\left(E_2\right)=\frac{\left( \begin{array}{c}
54 \\ 
2 \end{array}
\right)}{\left(\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{59}{5}\right)}*\left(\frac{1}{39}\right)+\frac{\left( \begin{array}{c}
54 \\ 
1 \end{array}
\right)}{\left( \begin{array}{c}
59 \\ 
5 \end{array}
\right)}*\left(\frac{38}{39}\right)=1.78388*{10}^{-5}$$ 
However the book answer is $\frac{45}{357599}=0.000125839$

What is wrong with my answer ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must also choose **which** three (or four) of five correct integers are matched:
$$ \mathbb{P}(E_1) = \frac{{5 \choose 3}{54 \choose 2}}{{59 \choose 5}} \cdot \frac{1}{39}  $$
You must remember about the same also during computation of $E_2$. Then everything should be OK.